# Failed to create CSSymbolicatorRef

Tags: objective-c

What exactly does this error statement mean?  I can't seem to find any documentation on the official Apple side, though I did stumble upon this - http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-90/libdtrace/dt_module_apple.c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that it can't link to a dynamic library. The most likely reason for this is that the offending executable was compiled against an incompatible SDK. Perhaps you ran xcodebuild for a command line tool on your Lion system with Xcode 4.5DP installed, and it linked against the 10.8 SDK? That tripped me up building appledoc from source just now. The solution is to xcode-select your release Xcode so that it'll xcodebuild with the 10.7 SDK, if that's your issue too; cleared me right up.